# Convert binary to ASCII and from ASCII to Letter in C function?

Tags: c, function

I've a homework that I have to do, but I'm wondering if in C we have some function that will actually convert the `8 bit` binary like for example `01010111` which is `87` and in letter is `W`

I'm going to be given a big set and I just have to store binary number in one array and convert after that I will combine all of them and return to the `main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtol.html) function can be used to parse a textual representation of a binary string by providing `2` as the last argument (indicating the string is representing a number in base 2).

Comment: @Ali: the first argument is the string containing the binary number, the second argument is a *pointer to a pointer to char* that is optional (you can provide `NULL`) which can be used to determine where the function *stopped* reading your string. The last argument is correct.

Comment: is it matter that it has to be `int` array or `char` array? || so you mean the second argument just to tell where to stop?

Comment: Also if you can point me out from the ASCII to letter if there is any function?

Comment: @Ali: The input must be a `char` array, and yes, the second argument is an output parameter, if you provide `NULL`, it is ignored (i.e. you don't care where the function has stopped) but if you provide a `char **` it will return the position within the first argument where it stopped processing. For example, if you provide `"101010xyz"`, the function will stop at `x` and return via the second argument the position of `x`.

Comment: @Ali: To convert the result of `strtol` into a `char`, simply cast it. For example, `char c = (char) strol("01010111", NULL, 2);` and you can write this character to the output with `printf("%c\n", c);`